# android - better way for activity navigation

Tags: android

My app having the 3 activities(A1,A2 and A3). The activities to be stay in the background when it goes another activity. For some instance I should redirect to A1 from A3. For this, I used the one Boolean counter. I set to true in A3 for that instance. In A2 onresume i checked the boolean value if it is true then i finished that activity(A2). finally A1 is onResume. But i think this is one solution but it's not better solution. can anyone suggest the better 
solution?

A3 Activity

```
status = true;// for some instance
```

A2 Activity

```
onResume()
{
if(status){finish();}
}
```

//A1 is onResumed

thanks

Comment: use navigation drawer http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Start Activity for Result If Result Is Positive Then Not Finish Else Finish Activity.,In That Case Have You Not Required Flag "status".

Comment: If it's ok to clear the backstack when returning to A1 you could start your activity with an intent flag "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" and launch A1 straight from A3. This will remove A2 and A3 from the backstack. However i'd also prefer using fragments if possible.

Comment: please provide the good links for fragments beginner because i was confused with this topic that's why i prefer this. thanks, for suggestion i will definitely follow fragments in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```

and setresult as you want.

and when u came on onActivityResult, you can check the result and finish the activity

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```